# Polylogarithm - derivative with respect to order

Tags: derivatives, special-functions

Does anybody know where I could find the expression for $$\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\mathrm{Li}_s(z)\bigg|_{s=0}$$ or something similar?

Comment: Please be more clear.

Comment: A good question.  There was a question yesterday where the answer was the derivative of $\mathrm{Li}_s(1/2)$ with respect to $s$.

Comment: +1. I never found anything about it. However, we can use integral representations. The problem is that we usually evaluate those integrals in terms of the above derivative. So, it's a closed circle as the dog trying to eat its tail.

Comment: Related to:  Find the derivative of a polylogarithm function, URL (version: 2015-03-18): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1194499

Answer (score 1):

For every $|z|<1$, we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\mathrm{Li}_s(z)\Big|_{s=0} = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log (n)\frac{z^n}{n^s} \Big|_{s=0} = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(n)\,z^n
$$

If it is not what you are looking for, could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Use partial integration, then you can relate the differentiation of $\text{Li}(j,x)$ to $\text{Li}(j,x)$ and $\text{Li}(j-1,x)$.

Comment: Using Mathematica, Li[n,x] is the same as PolyLog[n,x]. Mathematica gives D[PolyLog[n. -Exp[x],x]=PolyLog[n-1,Exp[x]]. I do not know if this helps. The Fermi Dirac integral Integrate[x^j/(1+Exp[x-u]),{x,0,Infinity}]=PolyLog[1+j,-Exp[u]].