# Find the derivative of a polylogarithm function

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative, polylogarithm

I was trying to find to which function the next series converges.
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln(n)z^n
$$
If we take the polylogarithm function $Li_s(z)$ defined as
$$
Li_s(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^s}
$$
Then it is easily seen that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln(n)z^n = - \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial s}Li_s(z)\right)_{s=0}
$$

> Now, my question is how to calculate $ \frac{\partial}{\partial s}Li_s(z)$, using an integral representation for $Li$, such as
>   $$
> Li_s(z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{zt^{s-1}}{e^t-z} dt
> $$

Is there any nice solution to this? All my attempts are unclear about it, especially because of the derivative of $\Gamma(s)$.

Comment: You can start to introduce polygamma functions for the Gamma derivative.

Comment: @Alizter , the problem of ussing the polygamma function $\psi^0(s)=\Gamma'(s)/\Gamma(s)$, is that it is not well defined when $s=0$.

Comment: Well it is well defined for an $s \in \Bbb R^+$ which is also the domain of the logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

You might write your series as
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \dfrac{(n-1) z^n}{(n-1)u + 1}\; du = \int_{0}^{1}\!{\frac {{z}^{2}}{u+1}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}\left(2,{\frac {u+1}{u}};\,{\frac {2\,u+1}{u}};\,z\right)}}
\, du
$$
but I don't think you'll get a closed form for the integral.

Comment: the $F_1$ stands for? However I do not see how your answer helps me to compute $\partial Li_s(z)/ \partial s$ using an integral representation.

Comment: ${}_2F_1(a,b; c; z)$ is the Gaussian hypergeometric function.  But as I said, I don't think you'll be able to "compute" it in the sense of getting a closed form.

Answer (score 1):

See the Eq.(18) of the article https://www.carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/MTWIII.pdf

$$
Li_0^{(m)} (z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} \zeta^{(m)}(-n) \frac{\log^n (z)}{n!} - \sum_{t=0}^m (-1)^t \left(\begin{matrix}m\\t\end{matrix}\right) \Gamma^{(t)}(1) \frac{\mathcal{L}^{m-t}}{\log z}
$$

Where $\mathcal{L} = \log(-\log z)$.

The same article discuss $\zeta^{(m)}(-n)$ at sec. 3.2.1. The $\Gamma$ derivative can be rewritten using that as $\Gamma^{'}(z) = \Gamma(z) \psi(z)$, where $\psi$ is the polygamma function of zeroth order.

At the wanted situation,

$$
Li_0^{'} (z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} \zeta^{'}(-n) \frac{\log^n (z)}{n!} 
- \frac{\log(-\log z)}{\log z}
+ \frac{\psi(1)}{\log z}
$$

This is just a way to rewrite the series, but may (I don't know) converge fast.

---

Another way is to use the Hankel contour integral representation (valid around $s=0$) (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Integral_representations)

$$
Li_s(e^{\mu}) = - \frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{2\pi i} \oint_H \frac{(-t)^{s-1}}{e^{t-\mu}-1} dt
$$

Taking the derivative with respect to $s$ and then making $s\rightarrow 0$,

$$
Li'_0(e^{\mu}) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_H \frac{1}{e^{t-\mu}-1} \frac{dt}{t} \left[ \gamma + \log (-t) \right] = \gamma Li_0(e^{\mu}) + \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_H \frac{\log (-t)}{e^{t-\mu}-1} \frac{dt}{t}
$$

Well, one problem still remains.